# python-sympy is_real returns None instead of True for 1/(1-x), where x is real

Tags: sympy, symbolic-math

sympy is_real returns None instead of True for 1/(1-x), where x is real

minimal example:

```
x = Symbol('x', real = True)
(1/(1-x)).is_real
```

How can I forego this, and check that expression is Real?

Comment: What if `x` is equal to 1?

Comment: Indeed, it would not be real. Still, it doesn't even if x = Symbol('x', real = True, positive = True).

Answer (score 2):

https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/assumptions/index.html

```
In [53]: x = Symbol('x', real = True)

In [54]: expr = (1/(1-x))

In [55]: ask(Q.real(x))
Out[55]: True

In [56]: ask(Q.real(expr))
Out[56]: True
```

`is_real` is a property that works from `_assumptions`.

```
In [57]: x._assumptions
Out[57]: 
{'real': True,
 'hermitian': True,
 'extended_real': True,
 'complex': True,
 'finite': True,
 'imaginary': False,
 ...}

In [58]: expr._assumptions
Out[58]: {}
```

Some expressions do evaluate their own assumptions, but this apparently does not.  `ask` is complex function, so it's hard to tell what it's doing beyond checking `_assumptions`.

Comment: Thank you, at least it works for simple cases.

Comment: This is actually a bug since it fails to take into account the possibility of the denominator being zero.

Answer (score 0):

If `x` is 1 then the expression is `1/0` which is not real. So `expr.is_real -> None` is the right answer. SymPy should only ever answer definitively if the expression always has that attribute, e.g. `(1/expr).is_real --> True`.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. You are right on this. Albeit, when x = Symbol('x', real = True, positive = True) it also returns None.

Comment: If x is positive it can still be equal to 1. If you make x *negative* then `is_real` will give True.